# Is it possible to generate a hyperlink to a Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am generating some reports after reading Simulink models. In this report I want to create hyperlinks refering to the path in the Model so that the person reading the report can navigate to this path just by clicking on this link. Have anyone had any experience with this or similar work?

Any help in this regard is muc appreciatged.

Best Regards,

Comment: Hi, Anybody have a clue whether this could be even done ?? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add links to a Word document by right-clicking a block-> requirements -> Add link to Word Selection. You will probably need to edit your link settings first, block-> requirements -> Link settings (which is quite straightforward). After that, just select the text you want to be linked in your document, go back to Simulink and click on "Add link to Word selection".

Comment: Hello JonDeLa, sorry. My question was regarding adding hyperlink to a Simulink Model from a document not adding a hyperlink to a document from Simulink Model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a license for [Simulink Requirements](https://se.mathworks.com/products/simulink-requirements.html) it is actually straight forward:

Right click on the block and select **Requirements**, **Copy URL to Clipboard**.

[image: Right click context menu]

In your case you could either create the links for the subsystem in question or to some input port.